# Перевод строчек `current password` и `Current password cannot be empty.`

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Переведите, пожалуйста, две строчки в форме изменения пароля:

> current password

и

> Current password cannot be empty.

скриншот:

> [image: форма изменения пароля]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки переведены.

Будут на сайте после подкачки Transifex и пересборки движка. Т.е. не раньше понедельника.